# In Python how can you roll up a list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working in python and I have created a list of lists that includes words and page numbers from a string I've already broken out into pages. This list contains words multiple times since they are present on multiple pages. I'd like to combine the page numbers for all words. For Example:

I currently have this list of lists:
`page_numbers = [['give',1], ['give',13], ['test', 12], ['test', 59]]`

and I'd like to see:

`['give',1,13]`, `['test', 12, 59]`

Any idea how to roll this list of lists up? TIA!

**Please note the example provided is only a small extract of the actual size of my list, so I'm looking for something dynamic.

Comment: Your example data is already sorted and grouped by word. Is that the case in real life?

Comment: it is not, the list is random

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to group your words with a list of pages.
That is, you'll make a dict that looks like:

```
{'give': [1, 13], 'test': [12, 59]}
```

Then you can assemble the lists by looping over the dict's items:

```
page_numbers = [['give',1], ['give',13], ['test', 12], ['test', 59]]

d = {}
for word, page in page_numbers:
    d.setdefault(word, []).append(page)

[[word] + pages for word, pages in d.items()]
# [['give', 1, 13], ['test', 12, 59]]
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without defining the dict? My list is actually 138051 and I just provided an extract above.

Comment: Using a dict will be *much* more efficient than other ways of doing this. Dicts allow O(1) access to keys so you don't need to spend time looping through some other structure. 138051 items should still be very fast. On my laptop making this dict with 200k items takes 45ms.